# Using Perl, how can I obtain the amount of free space on a local disk from WMIC on Windows?

Tags: perl, batch-file

I am getting server's disk usage using bat and perl script. Bat command is returning correct output in a file but it is in bytes, I am trying to get it converted to GB in perl script,  which is giving correct output on online IDE but not when am running on my server, can you tell me what other pre-requisites that I might need to check, other any issue in below code.

BAT:

```
wmic /OUTPUT:D:\advapp\PSMAG\Scripts\DailyOps\result.txt logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace /format:value

C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe  %PSMAGSCRIPTS%\DailyOps\dailyDiskCheck.pl
```

Perl:

```
# File generated by bat
my $soutput_file = "$sPSMAGSCRIPTS\\DailyOps\\result.txt";
open(SPACEFILE, "$soutput_file") or die "Can't open $soutput_file\n";
my $sLines;
{
    local $/ = undef;
    $sLines = <SPACEFILE>;
    print "file reaD\n";
}
if ( $sLines =~ m/(FreeSpace=.*)/i ) {
    print "" . $1 . "\n"; 
    if ($1 =~ m/FreeSpace=(\d+)/) {
        my $var = $1;
        $var /= 1073741824;
        print "FreeSpace is:$var GBs \n";
    }
    close(SPACEFILE);
}
else {
    print "no match";
}
```

Output I am getting:

file reaD

no match

Comment: `sPSMAGSCRIPTS` isn't set.

Comment: Please indent your code properly so that we can read it

Comment: Use lexical filehandles and 3-arg open, not bareword handles and 2-arg open. Don't quote `"$vars"` for no reason. Include `$!` in the error message.

Comment: The first step to debugging this would be to look at what's actually in `$sLines`.

Comment: You should start every Perl file with `use strict; use warnings;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Windows often writes text files in its own variant of UTF-16, and you need to decode that before you can use the data as characters. If you used

```
open SPACEFILE, '<:encoding(UTF-16)', $soutput_file
```

then you would see the characters you expected

I suggest running the `wmic` command from the Perl program.
If you let `wmic` send its output to STDOUT then it will be in ISO-8859-1, and mostly won't need decoding. You can you read the command's output through a pipe using `open`

This way you just need to run the Perl program and there is no need for the batch file as well

Like this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use constant GB => 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

my $sLines = do {
    open my $fh, '-|', q{wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace /format:value};
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};
print "File read\n";

if ( $sLines =~ /(FreeSpace=(\d+))/i ) {

    print "$1\n";

    my $bytes = $2;
    printf "FreeSpace is: %.2fGB\n", $bytes / GB;
}
else {
    print "no match";
}
```

#### output

```
File read
FreeSpace=10210951168
FreeSpace is: 9.51GB
```

Answer (score 2):

I would bypass the batch file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Number::Bytes::Human qw( format_bytes );

my $bytes_free = (split ' ', `wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace`)[1];

# Pretty print it (not really necessary)
print format_bytes( $bytes_free ), "\n";
```

Output:

```
C:\> perl tt.pl
1.5T
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Perl to do that; you may do it all in a Batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

wmic /OUTPUT:result.txt logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace /format:value
for /F %%a in ('type result.txt') do set "%%a"

echo FreeSpace = %FreeSpace% Bytes

set "group[1]=00000000%FreeSpace:~-9%"
set /A n=1, group[1]=1%FreeSpace:~-9% %% 1000000000
set "group[2]=%FreeSpace:~0,-9%"
if defined group[2] set "n=2"
set /A bin10=0, carry=0, bitPos=0
:nextBit
   for /L %%i in (%n%,-1,1) do set /A term=carry*1000000000+group[%%i], group[%%i]=term/2, carry=term%%2
   set /A "bin10[%bin10%]+=carry<<bitPos, carry=0, bitPos+=1"
   if %bitPos% equ 10 set /A bin10+=1, bitPos=0
   if !group[%n%]! equ 0 set /A n-=1
if %n% gtr 0 goto nextBit
set /A Int=bin10[3], Frac=100+bin10[2]*100/1024

echo FreeSpace = %Int%.%Frac:~-2% GigaBytes
```

Output example:

```
FreeSpace = 405032046592 Bytes
FreeSpace = 377.21 GigaBytes
```